# PyCharm: Difficulties importing module of package

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, anaconda, python-import

I am just getting started with PyCharm and have imported a project from Eclipse.

Running on a **virtual env**, I was able to register a compiled `pyd` file (PresPy). However, I still have an "unresolved reference" error. I also installed `colormath` from the PyCharm tooltip recommendation.

When running the project I strangely do not have the pyd-related error. Instead, the interpreter complains about a different module and not on the 'package level'.

### Error 1

**Unresolved reference: 'rgb_color'** in import statement:

```
#  These 4 lines work fine
import copy
import random
from math import pi, degrees
from configuration import Color, Condition #  From custom package

import colormath.color_diff
from PresPy import rgb_color #  Refers to a .pyd.
```

### Error 2

Stack trace:

```
....

File "x:\proj\src\color_logic\palette.py", line 14, in <module>
    import colormath.color_diff
ImportError: No module named colormath.color_diff

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Content root is the project folder. Source folders are in a separate `/src/` folder. An incomplete `setup.py` stub is located in the content root. The project ran without errors from Eclipse on a different installation of `pip install`:ed packages.

Below, this returns the source root folder (from [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901690/pycharm-module-import-error)):

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Under **Project: ... > Project Interpreter**<sup>1</sup> the packages `colormath` and `PresPy` are both listed.

<sub>1: PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3</sub>

<sub>Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901690/pycharm-module-import-error), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The Run configuration has to be changed to the corresponding virtual environment.