# Dependency management between multiple Python modules

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a project with multiple Python modules, each of which has its own virtual environment.

Project Structure:

```
data-reader (Python module)
    data_reader
        reader.py
    venv (virtual environment directory for data-reader)
    requirements.txt
data-writer (Python module)
    data_writer
        writer.py
    venv (virtual environment directory for data-writer)
    requirements.txt
commons (Python module)
    commons
        utils.py
    venv (virtual environment directory for commons)
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
```

I want to install `commons` as a dependency in both modules: `data-reader` and `data-writer` and preferably as an editable project dependency.

I created `setup.py` in commons and added the following requirement to the `requirements.txt` in both modules:

```
-e commons
```

When I activate the virtual environment for one of the modules and install its requirements I can run scripts from `commons` in the Python interpreter using the terminal, which is the expected and desired outcome, but in the `Intellij IDEA` IDE, I get an error underlining the import statement and with this error message: `Unresolved reference 'commons'`

```
from commons import utils
```

I don't know if it is a problem in `IDEA` or in the approach I am using.

- What is the recommended way to add and manage such dependencies?
- Is adding this dependency as an editable project one a good idea in the first place or there is other recommended approaches?

Comment: and what error message does ide show?

Comment: your approach is good, there is no serious problem in it. When your product codebase grows, you always end up with something similar.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the error message, which is `Unresolved reference 'commons'`

Comment: The solution which will work, but it is hard to maintain: when you change commons, create a sdist release using setup.py, and then in other modules install that release with pip.

Comment: actually, it is a huge overkill to use many packages for a small project, written by one man. While project grows, it is split in such packages, and every package is developed independently, and has its own vcs repository

Comment: Thank you for you comments. The project is not small and it is of course versioned. Our team is not small either and that's why we care very much about the best practices and we are trying to keep the required manual configuration as minimum as possible for other developers when pulling any changes.

Comment: As far as I have seen running `pip` with the option `-e` creates the same source distribution as `sdist` which running it manually didn't help in the IDEA problem

Comment: in pycharm in `file -> settings -> Project (project name) -> project interpreter ` did you set it to the proper venv?  This is different from activating the venv in a command shell.

Comment: Yes, every module has the correct interpreter which is his virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related with Intellij / Pycharm.

You should be choosing the interpreter used by Pycharm to match the one of the virtualenvironment.

If you don't, Pycharm will be using the default python interpreter where the libraries you are importing are not installed.

You can select it with `settings -> preference -> Project Interpreter (in the left menu bar)`.
Then add the local virtualenv to the specific python project, for the three of them.

If it helps, the official documentation is:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is indeed related to IntelliJ/PyCharm. Actually, it turned out that it is a very old issue which is not getting fixed properly: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-976
Unfortunately, your suggested workaround does not also work for me, that is something I am doing anyway to ease up some other processes.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been a while, I am posting an answer for other readers. The approach turned out to be good for us and working fine so far.

The issue is with IntelliJ/PyCharm and it turned out to be a very old one which is still not properly fixed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-976. A couple of workarounds are reported in the issue itself. I personally have not tried all of them but none of what I have tried so far worked for me.

Another thread is available here: [PyCharm does not recognize modules installed in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193365/pycharm-does-not-recognize-modules-installed-in-development-mode)